# find the value of $ S = \sum _{k=1}^{\infty }\left(\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k+1}}{(k)(2k+1)}\right)$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Find the value of $\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{10}+\frac{1}{21}-\frac{1}{36}+...$

I have no idea how to solve this infinite sum, I appreciate any help, thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you want to find the sum $\displaystyle\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \left(\dfrac{(-1)^{k+1}}{2k+1}\right)$ or $\dfrac13 - \dfrac1{10} + \dfrac1{21} - \dfrac1{36}+\cdots$?

Comment: The question in your title and the question in your question are not the same.

Comment: my bad, I forgot to put a k in the denominator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\frac S2=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{2k(2k+1)}
=\sum_{k=1}^\infty(-1)^{k+1}\left(\frac1{2k}-\frac1{2k+1}\right)
=\sum_{k=1}^\infty(-1)^{k+1}\int_0^1(x^{2k-1}-x^{2k})\,dx
=\int_0^1 \frac{x-x^2}{1+x^2}\,dx$$
etc.

Comment: Holy cow that's incredible! Where do you learn this technique?

Comment: This is a well-known method...

Comment: I still do not understand the method you used and I don't even know it's name

Answer (score 1):

Observe you have
\begin{align}
\operatorname{Log}(1+i)=\sum^\infty_{n=1} (-1)^n\frac{i^n}{n}=\sum^\infty_{k=1}\frac{(-1)^k}{2k}+i\sum^\infty_{k=1}\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{2k-1}
\end{align}
where $\operatorname{Log}z$ is the principal branch.
Hence it follows
\begin{align}
\operatorname{Log}(1+i)=\log 2+ i\arg (1+i) = \log 2 + i\frac{\pi}{4}
\end{align} 
which means
\begin{align}
\sum^\infty_{k=1}\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{2k+1}=1-\frac{\pi}{4}.
\end{align}

For the other problem, we see that
\begin{align}
\sum^\infty_{k=1}(-1)^{k+1} \frac{1}{2k(2k+1)} = \sum^\infty_{k=1}(-1)^{k+1}\left( \frac{1}{2k}-\frac{1}{2k+1}\right)=-\frac{1}{2}\sum^\infty_{k=1}\frac{(-1)^k}{k}-\frac{\pi}{4} = \frac{1}{2}\log 2+\frac{\pi}{4}-1.
\end{align}

Comment: Wait, but I am trying solve for k(2k+1)in the denominator not 2k+1

Comment: @raylin your original problem was the one I solved.

Comment: WolframAlpha has a slightly different answer: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+(-1)%5E(n%2B1)%2F(n*(2n%2B1)),+n%3D1+to+infinity

Comment: I think the $-\dfrac\pi4$ should be $\dfrac\pi4$.